# Items/Records re-ordering?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, database, performance

Assume that on a multiple-user application that the same request may be initiated by multiple users at the same time, which these requests at the end will be some ajax calls to some server-side action we have a routine executed by that action/method on server as below:

routine task : it is responsible to do the reordering such that, imagine items are not connected to each other, there is no doubly linked-list data structure in place but all items have an assumed ordering by default and represented to users by that order, when an add item , or delete item , or update item operation is initiated by those ajax calls, ordering will be different as the entry is like FIFO.

currently I need to update all the records, orderNumber column to keep track of all the changed, On an update operation because items are movable in the user interface and users have the facility of a drag and drop interaction, items can go up or down the original ordered list and change those orderings.

what would you suggest as the most efficient method for keeping track of these ordering changes in which will have the least performance cost on server as well as keeping an acceptable user interaction for users?

Development Platform is ASP.NET MVC4 , Persistence using SQL Server

EDIT:

after reading the first answer I have to mention the fact that, the problem is not a real-time or multi-cast message issued for all users from server or issued by an initiated change from one user to get broad-casted to all other users.
items are user specific, some users may have hundreds of items , and some may have a handful or less

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr) (or any equivalent technology, but since you are in the .net stack, it feels more natural).

In SignalR you can create Hubs, keep track of the clients connected to that hub and even create groups of users. You can send messages to that hub either from the server side (by grabbing the hub context) or from any client.

If you have N users connected, each drag-n-drop operation resulting in re-ordering the elements in the screen will traduce on a message being sent from the user enacting the re-order to let other clients know the order has changed. Users that receive such "orderChanged" message can then issue an ajax call to the server to get latest.

**EDIT:**

Even when it is not a multicast, as clarified in the first comment below, SignalR is a good fit. 
In your hub you can keep track of the user connection(s) (plural since it is possible a single user can be logged in from different clients) and send messages individually based on what changed.

When a supervisor changes a user's ToDo list, you can invoke methods on the clients the affected user is using, so he knows his list changed.

Using the same concept you can send messages to other clients for the same user, if he changes his own ToDo list.

SignalR is *really* flexible and it will be clear for you as soon as you take a look at the docs.

Comment: I like your through answer but I think I made a mistake in defining the problem, you assumed it is a multi-cast change but items are specific to each user, like a todo list for each user, would you consider, update your answer based on the fact, I would truly appreciate this, thanks